# how to check regex starts and ends with regex

Tags: java, regex

I am having the regex for capturing string if they are in between double quote and not start or end with `/`.

But the regex solution which I wanted.

```
The regex should not capture
```

Condition 1. Capture text between two double or single quotes. 
Condition 2. But it shouldn't capture if starts with [ and ends with ]
Condition 3. But it shouldn't if starts with /" and ends with /' or starts with /" and ends with /'

Example:

REGEX: `\"(\/?.)*?\"`

Input: `Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.unescapeJson("test"), "m2m:cin.as"),"payloads_ul.test"),"[/"Dimming Value/"]",input["test"]["in"])`

output:

```
captured output:
1. "test"
2. "m2m:cin.as"
3. "payloads_ul.test"
4. [/"Dimming Value/"]
5. "test"
6. "in"
```

Expected result:

```
1. "test"
2. "m2m:cin.as"
3. "payloads_ul.test"
4. [/"Dimming Value/"]
```

Condition 1 explanation:
Capture the text between double or single quotes.
example: 
input : `"test","m2m:cin.as"`
output: "test","m2m:cin.as"

Condition 2 explanation:
If the regex is between starts with `[` and ends with `]` but it is having double or single quote then also it should not capture.

example:
input: `["test"]`
output: it should not capture

Condition 3 explanation:
In the above-expected result for the input `"[/"Dimming Value/"]"` there is a two-time double quote but is capturing only one excluding `/"`. So, the output is `[/"Dimming Value/"]`. Like this, I want if `/'` (`single quote preceded by /`).

Note:
For input `"[/"Dimming Value/"]" or '[/'Dimming Value/']'`, here although the text is between double quote and single quote and having `[` and `]` it should not ignore the string. The output should be [/"Dimming Value/"].

Comment: Do you want javascript or java?

Comment: Please edit your question, it is unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: @WJS, I want the solution in java, I have edited.

Comment: @SebastianNielsen, Thanks for the reply I have updated the question with an explanation. If that doesn't  clear your doubt let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, you want to capture text between double quotes, except:

- if initial double quotes prefixed by **[** or final double quotes suffixed by **]**
- doubles quotes prefixed by **/** should not be the begin or end of matched text

I don't know if you want also capture text between single quotes, because you text is not complete clear.

For create a non capture group with negative matching of prefixed chars, you need a group of type **Negative Lookbehind**, with syntax **(?<!prefix that you dont want)**, but this is not present on java or javascript regex engine.

The best regex that I build to return what you want for you example (but only work on PHP or python (you can check it on site [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) or similar)) is:

```
(?<![\[/])\"(?!\])(\/?.)*?\"(?![\]/])
```

I added the restriction for don't match if initial double quotes suffixed by **]** to prevent match **"]["** on text **["test"]["in"]**

Anyway, this will not solve your problem, since will not work within java or javascript engine!

Do you have any way to process the results, and exclude the bad matches?

If so, you can match bad prefix and bad suffix and exclude it from the results:

```
[\[]?\"(\/?.)*?\"[\]]?
```

this will return:

```
"test"
"m2m:cin.as"
"payloads_ul.test"
"[/"Dimming Value/"]"
["test"]
["in"]
```

Full javascript code, including pos processing:

```
'Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.unescapeJson("test"), "m2m:cin.as"),"payloads_ul.test"),"[/"Dimming Value/"]",input["test"]["in"])'
.match(/[\[]?\"(\/?.)*?\"[\]]?/g).filter(s => !s.startsWith('[') && !s.endsWith(']'))
```

this will return:

```
"test"
"m2m:cin.as"
"payloads_ul.test"
"[/"Dimming Value/"]"
```

EDIT:
equivalent java code:

```
CharSequence yourStringHere = "Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.unescapeJson(\"test\"), \"m2m:cin.as\"),\"payloads_ul.test\"),\"[/\"Dimming Value/\"]\",input[\"test\"][\"in\"])";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[\\[]?\\\"(\\/?.)*?\\\"[\\]]?")
        .matcher(yourStringHere);
while (m.find()) {
    String s = m.group();
    if (!s.startsWith("[") && !s.endsWith("]")) {
        allMatches.add(s);
    }
}
```